# Jhipster Webpack build failed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, jhipster

whenever i try to create a app using jhipster, the following error is thrown:

```
sunvalley@0.0.0 webpack /home/prashanth/workspace/sunvalley
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.dev.js" "--progress" "--profile"

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 139

npm ERR! sunvalley@0.0.0 webpack: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.dev.js" "--progress" "--profile"`


Error: ERROR! webpack:build failed.

at Environment.error (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:157:40)

at module.exports.error (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2064:18)

at module.exports.end (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/client/index.js:410:18)

at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:399:25)

at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25

at new Promise (<anonymous>)

at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19

at self.env.runLoop.add.completed (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:400:11)

at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)

at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
```

Error Log:

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'webpack:build' ]

2 info using npm@5.6.0

3 info using node@v8.11.1

4 verbose run-script [ 'prewebpack:build', 'webpack:build', 'postwebpack:build' ]

5 info lifecycle sunvalley@0.0.0~prewebpack:build: sunvalley@0.0.0

6 info lifecycle sunvalley@0.0.0~webpack:build: sunvalley@0.0.0

7 verbose lifecycle sunvalley@0.0.0~webpack:build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle sunvalley@0.0.0~webpack:build: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/prashanth/workspace/sunvalley/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin

9 verbose lifecycle sunvalley@0.0.0~webpack:build: CWD: /home/prashanth/workspace/sunvalley

10 silly lifecycle sunvalley@0.0.0~webpack:build: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:build:main' ]

11 silly lifecycle sunvalley@0.0.0~webpack:build: Returned: code: 139  signal: null

12 info lifecycle sunvalley@0.0.0~webpack:build: Failed to exec webpack:build script

13 verbose stack Error: sunvalley@0.0.0 webpack:build: `npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:build:main`

13 verbose stack Exit status 139

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)

13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)

13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)

13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)

13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)

14 verbose pkgid sunvalley@0.0.0

15 verbose cwd /home/user/workspace/sunvalley

16 verbose Linux 4.13.0-38-generic

17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "webpack:build"

18 verbose node v8.11.1

19 verbose npm  v5.6.0

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 139

22 error sunvalley@0.0.0 webpack:build: `npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:build:main`

22 error Exit status 139

23 error Failed at the sunvalley@0.0.0 webpack:build script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 139, true ]

Comment: Exit code 139 typically means a segfault in node. Sometimes it can be fixed by switching to another node version. Have you same failure when running a prod build `mvnw -Pprod clean package` ? This would be interesting because maven uses same node/npm versions but installed locally (in node sub folder of your project).

Comment: Alternatively you could try installing node 8.9.4. Which OS are you running?

Comment: this error was thrown when i was using lubuntu 17.10 32 bit. I installed the 64 bit version of lubuntu and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Great. It was probably due to `--max_old_space_size=4096` which exceeded 32 bit memory. If so we should probably require it in doc or in generator.